# sharedpreferences not loading or saving

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, storage

I'm trying to used sharedpreferences for when a user chooses a specific custom image they want in their storage for a part of a grid of images. I want the image they chose to show up even after they close the application and reopen it. The problem I'm having is that the sharedpreferences don't seem to be working. Nothing shows up as the background image for the grid item they've selected once they've closed the app or even just pressed the back button.

Do I have to create a sharedpreferences file myself? I can't figure out how to get to it or create one if so using androidstudio.

Here's my code for the class (Sorry if it's long and messy...I am new to coding and still testing things):

```
  public class editCreations extends Activity {

    public int mPosition = 0;
    protected static Sounds sound = new Sounds();
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private String mOutputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    private Drawable mImageFileName;
    private Button recordBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;
    private Button playBtn;
    private Button stopPlayBtn;
    private ImageButton imgBtn;
    private Drawable bg;
    private  String mPicturePath;



    private ImageAdapter img = new ImageAdapter(this);





    View.OnClickListener playListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(editCreations.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFile);

        recordBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_record_button);
        recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start(view);
            }
        });

        stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_stop_record_button);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stop(view);
            }
        });

        playBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_play_button);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                play(view);
            }
        });

        stopPlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_stop_button);
        stopPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopPlay(view);
            }
        });

        imgBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        Intent extra = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = extra.getExtras();

        // gave mPosition a default int to debug and find problem -> found it
        mPosition = extras.getInt("position");
        getSelectedFile(mPosition);

        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });




    }

    public void start (View view) {
        try {

            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recordBtn.setEnabled(false);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(true);

        Toast.makeText(editCreations.this, mPosition + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void stop(View view){
        try {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;

            stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            recordBtn.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop recording...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play(View view) {
        try{
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mOutputFile);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();

            playBtn.setEnabled(false);
            stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start play the recording...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopPlay(View view) {
        try {
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
                playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(false);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop playing the recording...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getSoundPosition(int position) {
        mOutputFile = mOutputFile + "/Lollatone_clip_" + mPosition + ".3gpp";

        // use to get proper image and sound files and edit output file to proper name
    }

    public void getSelectedFile(int position) {
            switch (mPosition) {
                case 0:
                    imgBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_0);
                    imgBtn.refreshDrawableState();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    imgBtn.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicturePath));
                    imgBtn.refreshDrawableState();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    imgBtn.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicturePath));
                    imgBtn.refreshDrawableState();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    imgBtn.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicturePath));
                    imgBtn.refreshDrawableState();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    imgBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_4);
                    imgBtn.refreshDrawableState();
                    break;
            }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_creations, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

       if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
           Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
           String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                   filePathColumn, null,null,null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();

           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
           mPicturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
           cursor.close();

           imgBtn.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicturePath));

           imgBtn.refreshDrawableState();
           // String picturePath contains the path of
           // selected image
       }
   }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //need an editor object to make preference changes
        // all objects are from android.context.Context
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("img_" + mPosition, mPicturePath);

        editor.commit();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mPicturePath = sharedPref.getString("img_" + mPosition, "img_" + mPosition);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `SharedPreferences` correctly but you are not placing the code in the right activity lifecycle methods. You are reading the preference on `onCreate()` and saving on `onStop()` so maybe what you can do it save the preference on `onPause()` (to make sure it gets saved earlier) and reload on `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()` (the latter only occurs once in the life cycle of an activity).

Also, you might want to check if `Context.getSharedPreferences()` would be a better choice for this, since it's shared between more than just one activity.

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot to update the image in onResume. It does work now, thanks!